# Which tools should I look for, that might help me analyze digitally recorded music, so I can better learn how to play it?

Tags: practice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software that slows down music to help in transcribing.](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/123/software-that-slows-down-music-to-help-in-transcribing)

I'm looking to study specific soloes and improvisations from recordings of live performances - my ear, however, is not very well trained and I don't have perfect pitch. What tools can I use that will help me better analyze the music (possibly by splitting out instruments or tracks from an existing recording, or automatically identifying chord progressions and changes, or any other help)?

Comment: It's not an exact dupe, since the scope of that one is much narrower.  Personally, I'm not entirely sure whether these are good questions, but I will not vote to close till the community has more of a consensus.

Comment: @Matthew Read Maybe my question isn't clear (can you help?) - I'm looking for suggestions for tool types to try, not necessarily specific ones. A good answer, for me, might be "software to slow down music, software that splits out tracks, auto-tuners that properly identify key and tempo"

Comment: @blueberryfields did you look at the linked question and its answers? @Matthew flagging as a duplicate is also a way to point the asker at other relevant answers, even if the question in question (so to speak) is not closed.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs You can just comment with the link, no need to flag or vote to close. @blueberryfields I think it's sort of a shopping-recommendation question.  It might be better to ask for good methods of helping you analyze music, and then ask about tools that can help you do that.  Again, I'm not really sure whether that's a good fit for the site or not.

Comment: @Matt full ack, but in this case I also thought it was a duplicate :)

Comment: It is a duplicate of the other question, I agree. Close! :)