# Looking for fingering advice for fast opening section of "Cynthia's Battle" theme

Tags: piano, fingering

I've just started learning this [arrangement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3CC2EnNHuN4&ab_channel=marasy8) by Marasy8 on youtube from a nostalgic video game of mine (Cynthia's Battle theme for any Gen IV'ers), and I'm at the bit right after the opening chords. The left hand went down easily enough, but Marasy8's fingering isn't as easy to see for the right hand. I'd usually go with what feels most natural to me (I've linked my [interpretation](https://youtu.be/X9gvypRBOI8) here), but considering how fast this piece plays and the fact that I don't have a ton of experience, I don't want to start speeding things up until I'm sure my fingering's the best it can be.

To keep the question as self-contained as possible, I'll provide the following information in addition to the links, which may be susceptible to rot. I could not find any sheets for this particular arrangement after checking thoroughly for them online, so I've instead opted to learn with the help of a Synthesia video I found on youtube.

The notes with my fingerings are as follows (E5 would denote an E is played with the finger 5), with the first E occurring in the 6th octave, i.e. E6:

E5 Bb2 C#3 F#1 Bb4 C#1 F#4 G5 F#4 E3 Bb1 C#2 F#1 Bb3 F#1 G1 A2 F#4 E3 C#2 Bb1

Is there anything I could change before I commit it to muscle memory?

Comment: This fingering is easier to discern if one [slows down the video](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/103584/how-can-i-slow-down-a-youtube-video-im-trying-to-analyze-or-transcribe). Perhaps that will give you the solution you need. Otherwise, please add to the question an indication of the notes being played and your current fingering. that will allow someone to answer without transcribing the recording and in a way that will be helpful to future readers.

Comment: @Aaron I see, thanks for pointing that out. I did try playing the video frame by frame, and some strokes were simply not discernible between frames. I will edit my question with the information you've suggested, but I find it strange that you've suggested an edit but still chose to close-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with your fingering. Allowing it's comfortable for you, committing the fingering to memory seems fine.

That said, here is my own preferred fingering. Try it out and see if you want to adopt any or all of it.

```
5-2-4   1-5-1   4-5-4   3-1-4   1-4-2   1-2-5   4-2-1
```

This fingering depends on a very quick release of finger 5 that allows the hand to "retract" back to its natural relaxed position. If finger 5 lingers on its note, then I would adjust this way:

```
5-2-3   1-4-1   4-5-4   3-1-4   1-4-2   1-2-5   4-2-1
    *     *
```

Comment: I had to check through my question for mistakes and the original arrangement to see if I'd heard wrong, but I couldn't find anything erroneous on my part. Could you explain to me how you've arrived at F# for the 19th note rather than E?

Comment: @Brxan I'm not sure I can give you a satisfying answer, I just clearly hear the F#. As a step in that direction, you might listen for the fact that the pitch preceding the final C# is lower than it rather than higher. You could try slowing the video -- YouTube will preserve the pitch.

Comment: Would the F# you hear not be the 18th note? I hear an E, C# and Bb after it. The same is reflected in a Synthesia video that seems to be accurate to my ears, which I could link if you're sure you haven't misread my original post.

Comment: @Brxan It's the eighteenth note -- one octave below the F# just before. You're welcome to link the Synthesia video. I'll take a look when i can.

Comment: Gladly, you can find it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yscu6KSMG3M . No rush.

Comment: @Brxan Okay, that clarifies things. I don't hear the E at all in the first recording, but now I see she's playing the F# with her left hand, and the E is clearly present in the Synthesia version. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I see, glad we're on the same page. I can see the benefits of your preferred fingering - some stretches are shortened and the jump to get finger 4 to the last F# is eliminated, making the transition to the final notes feel noticeably safer. That last part's definitely the more reliable route to go.

Comment: @Brxan Glad that helped. It was a successful collaboration.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.