# What is the difference between a mordent and turn?

Tags: piano, ornaments

I've tried Googling the difference between a turn and mordent, but all the answers are really vague. I also couldn't find any helpful images that explain to me. I'm really confused right now. Turns and mordents both seem so similar to me, and right now the only differences I can see are their symbols. Could someone please explain the difference?

Comment: Here is an example: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/116704/beethoven-sonata-op-49-no-2-bar-12-trill

Comment: @GrandAdagio Thanks! That's a turn, not a mordent, right?

Comment: Yes, as Aaron said in his answer to that question (I mistakenly called it a 'trill' there).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **Mordent**: includes only one note either above or below the main note.
- **Turn**: includes both one pitch above and one pitch below the main note.

Below is a simple example of a "lower mordent". Note how the main note is struck, followed by its lower neighbor, then a return to the main note.

[image: Lower mordent: E-D-E]

And here is one possibility for a turn, with notes both above and below the main note.

[image: Turn: F-E-D-E]

The specific executions depends on musical context, but will always maintain the characteristics of a single ornamental pitch in a mordent and two ornamental pitches in a turn.

One of the primary sources for information on (Baroque era) ornaments is found in the Klavierbüchlein für Wilhelm Friedemann Bach, by J.S. Bach. An image can be [found on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music)#Baroque_music), which also gives additional notated examples of [mordents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music)#Mordent) and [turns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music)#Turn).

Comment: One note to add: In modern english use the term *mordent* would be primarily applied to the prall trill, i.e. the *upper mordent*. The mordent in question is the proper baroque mordent (the prall trill was not really used in Bach’s times) is usually known as *reverse mordent* or *lower mordent*. So when people talk about a *mordent* in baroque keyboard music they generally mean what is now known as *reverse mordent*. If you see a sign that looks like an upper mordent that is in fact a trill.

Comment: And I guess we should note that there are other possibilities for "turns", for example, beginning on the target note, and then up-back-down-back... depending on context.

Comment: It could be worth expanding this answer since I feel like the Romantic approach to the turn more often starts from the target note? as paul suggests, and as covered in https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/116704/beethoven-sonata-op-49-no-2-bar-12-trill