# How to play a turn?

Tags: notation, rhythm, ornaments

What does the turn notation symbol mean to play rhythmically?
what if it is not on the note but in between 2 notes? thanks

Comment: Turns can be played rhythmically in several different ways depending on the context. Please post the context in which the question came up, and you'll get the best answers. (Also, if you haven't already, search for "turn" and [tag:ornaments], because there have been many related questions. Yours may be covered.)

Comment: @foxrox what instrument?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between a mordent and turn?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/123744/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mordent-and-turn)

Comment: One simple answer, and not covered at the proposed duplicate: A turn doesn't make *strict* implications about rhythm. Even when it's clear which pitches are intended, it often allows or even expects some rubato and bending of rhythm, e.g. to "stretch" the main note and compress the ornament for an energetic feel, or to do the opposite for a languorous, expressive feel.

Comment: Please give us the context so your question can be reopened or pointed to a helpful existing Q-A.