# How do I make a percussive backbeat and pluck another three string simultaneously?

Tags: acoustic-guitar, percussion

I am trying to learn the fingerstyle version of "take me to church" by Hozier.

[image]

Tab is from *[Hozier – Take Me To Church Tab by Kaminari | Songsterr Tabs with Rhythm](https://www.songsterr.com/a/wsa/kaminari-hozier-take-me-to-church-tab-s477756)*.

But how do I make a percussive backbeat with the inner part of my thumb and pluck another three/two strings simultaneously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of this tab/arrangement has posted a video of himself playing it.

You can see that the top strings are strummed with the top of the middle or index finger nail.  That way, you're not trying to do a downward thump and upward pluck at the same time.  Both motions go down together.  (And remember that youtube lets you [play back this video in slow motion](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/103584/70803) too)