# Chopin Prelude Op. 28 No. 1: A mysterious mutated note in the 12th bar?

Tags: theory, harmony, chord-theory, classical-music, chopin

In Chopin Prelude Op. 28 No. 1 (C major) has a particularly mysterious mutated note in the 12th bar shown in the red box (this note does not repeat the voice of the previous blue box):

### Question

**Is there a good reason why Chopin chooses to only mutate this note in the red box, not in the other bars?**

[image: Chopin op. 28 no. 1, with m. 12 highlighted]

If you look carefully, every bar has a right-hand melody with 5 notes. In each bar, you can see the fourth note always repeats the second note in the same bar; the only exception is what I highlighted in the red box and the blue box.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an error in the score. The D should be an E. For example, see the Mikuli edition ([IMSLP](https://s9.imslp.org/files/imglnks/usimg/e/e2/IMSLP111373-PMLP02344-FChopin_Preludes,_Op.28_Mikuli.pdf))

[image: Chopin op. 28, no. 1 m. 12]

Comment: My ear cannot logically tell me whether https://youtu.be/UtyL4hJrypQ?t=15 (at 15 sec) does  Vladimir Ashkenazy play E or play D in the fourth note in the right-hand melody? Vladimir Ashkenazy seems to play a sound like D to me.

Comment: @wonderich If you [slow down the video](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/103584/70803) to half speed, you can hear the E with reasonable clarity (mostly because the D would stand out noticeably if that's what he played).