# How can my ear training be made better? (For Guitarist)

Tags: guitar, ear-training

I was looking for the lead (the music that starts the song) in the Hotel California Song. But I am having trouble locating the tab. Even after listening more than 50 times, I still cannot locate the guitar tab.Additionally, I have a very quick hand and can play any chord.

I am extremely discouraged.Furthermore, I do not want to copy the tab from YouTube or other website.

How can my ear training be made better?

Comment: There are many, many questions on this site about improving ear training. Please read through some of those to see if they answer your question. If they don't, then please update your question to indicate what issue(s) are left unaddressed.

Comment: @Aaron Could you check and search the question for me?

Comment: That's your job when posting on this site — to do some basic research first. If you hover over the downvote button, you'll see that it says "This question does not show any research effort."

Comment: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/123/software-that-slows-down-music-to-help-in-transcribing

Comment: A teacher and/or loads of practice is what has served most of us. It's not an easy job, but knowing scales and chords is a very good start. That apart, there are many inaccurate tabs out there.

Comment: The wording in this question is really confusing. The word "tab" refers to a particular way of writing music down visually, but you seem to be describing trying to _hear_ the tab, which is impossible. I'm guessing that when you wrote "locating the tab," you meant "making out what the notes are," but I'm not completely sure.

Comment: Yes@TannerSwett I am referring to music notes, not tabs

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not distinguish itself from the many other ear-training questions on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, it's all about practicing and just hearing the same things over and over enough times. Playing by ear is definitely challenging at first. My advice is to break up the song into manageable chunks by pausing it. Try listening to the first five notes, and then find those on your instrument. If that's too hard, just do the first four notes, and so on. Then move on to the next chunk of notes, learn them, and add them to the first part. Soon you'll know all the notes and be able to practice it, and each song you learn by ear will get a little easier.